# I want to delete many form contents

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

ReferenceError: form is not defined

I want to deleate 6 form's contents.
I try this code but there is error message.

```
function clearForm0_1_2_3_4_5(){
var form0 = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/~~~~~~~~~~~');
var items = form.getItems();
while(items.length > 0){
form0.deleteItem(items.pop());
form0.deleteAllResponses();}



var form1 = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/~~~~~~~~~~~~~');
var items = form.getItems();
while(items.length > 0){
form1.deleteItem(items.pop());
form1.deleteAllResponses();}

var form2 = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/~~~~~~~~~~~~~');
var items = form.getItems();
while(items.length > 0){
form2.deleteItem(items.pop());
form2.deleteAllResponses();}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `form.getItems()`, because `form` doesn't exist. Use the correct form variable instead.

```
function clearForm0_1_2_3_4_5(){
  var form0 = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/~~~~~~~~~~~');
  var items = form0.getItems();
  // ...
  
  var form1 = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/~~~~~~~~~~~~~');
  var items = form1.getItems();
  // ...
  
  var form2 = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/~~~~~~~~~~~~~');
  var items = form2.getItems();
  // ...
}
```

Since you're doing the same thing to all of the forms, I'd also rewrite it like this:

```
function clearForms() {
  var formUrls = [
    'https://docs.google.com/forms/ONE',
    'https://docs.google.com/forms/TWO',
    'https://docs.google.com/forms/THREE',
    'https://docs.google.com/forms/FOUR',
    'https://docs.google.com/forms/FIVE',
  ];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < formUrls.length; i++) {
    var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrls[i]);
    var items = form.getItems();
    while(items.length > 0) {
      form.deleteItem(items.pop());
    }
    form.deleteAllResponses();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your script never declared `form`, it's declaring `form0`, `form1`, `form2` but the followwing line after them are using `form`.